# How do I write a subquery to concatenate Last name and First name using another table in database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm using 2 tables, `Orders` and `Employees`. Both have IDs of employees. I need to get a total amount of orders completed by each separate employee.

I want my result to be this: full name, total orders.

What I could get is: employee ID, total orders.

I can't connect `Order.EmployeeID` with `Employees.EmployeeID`, even when using CAST or CONVERT.

I can make separate queries to concat names, and to show orders by employee ID, but I can't wrap my mind how to make a subquery to give me full name of each employee and total amount of their orders.

```
SELECT 
    [dbo].[Orders].EmployeeID AS Seller,
    COUNT(OrderID) AS Amount
FROM
    [dbo].[Orders]
JOIN 
    [dbo].[Employees] ON [dbo].[Employees].EmployeeID = [dbo].[Orders].EmployeeID
GROUP BY 
    [dbo].[Orders].EmployeeID;
```

I expect the following result:

```
|Name        |TotalOrders|
+------------+-----------+
|Johnny Bravo| 120       |
```

Current result however is:

```
|ID|TotalOrders|
+--+-----------+
|1 |120        |
```

Comment: You need to select the columns that you want.  If you select the id, you'll get the id.  If you select the names, you'll get the names.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. You are clearly using SQL Server here (due to the `dbo` schema), but pelase don't tag multiple RDBMS when asking a question.

Comment: `SELECT [dbo].[Orders].EmployeeID AS Seller,[dbo].[Employees].FullName, ....`

Comment: Three and four part naming in the select list has been deprecated for a few versions now. Using an alias is a much better approach. Alternately just the table name is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply concatenate them, like this for example

```
SELECT 
    o.EmployeeID AS Seller,
    CONCAT(e.FirstName + ' ', e.LastName) AS FullName, 
    COUNT(o.OrderID) AS Amount
FROM
    [dbo].[Orders] o
JOIN 
    [dbo].[Employees] e ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
GROUP BY 
    o.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName
```

You could also do this

```
(e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName) as FullName
```

But beware of this, when one of the columns is `NULL` then the result will also be `NULL`

Then you would have to do this

```
(isnull(e.FirstName, '') + ' ' + isnull(e.LastName, '')) as FullName
```

Therefore, the `CONCAT` function is easier, it will convert `NULL` values into empty strings for you.

See also this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2017)

**EDIT**
As noted by Sean Lange, it is better to do

```
Concat(e.FirstName + ' ', e.LastName) as FullName,
```

in stead of

```
Concat(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) as FullName,
```

Because this way you will have no leading spaces when the firstname is null

Comment: I like to do something like CONCAT(e.FirstName + ' ' , e.LastName) That way if the first name is NULL you don't end up with leading spaces. ;) This answer is a good way to go. +1

Comment: Hello, thank you for response. The one with isnull seems to work just fine, CONCAT doesn't work for me: 'Concat' is not a recognized built-in function name. When i add {fn it allows me to use it but allows me to only pass 2 arguments. Should I concat the concat?

Comment: @Vitaliyehh If the concat is not working for you, than what version of sql server are you using ? It should be available starting from 2012

Comment: {fn Concat(e.FirstName + ' ',e.LastName)} as FullName,  :this fixed it for me

Comment: This isn't necessarily related to OP's dilemma, but a possibility is an Employee with no Orders in the Orders table.  So this may need to be addressed with a LEFT JOIN; with the Employee table on the left side and the Orders table on the right.

Comment: @Zorkolot Yes that is possible off course. I just started from his original query, its up to the OP to know if he needs `left` or `inner` join

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [dbo].[Orders].EmployeeID AS Seller,Concat ([Orders].FirstName,[Orders].Lastname) fullname,
       COUNT(OrderID) AS Amount
FROM [dbo].[Orders]
     JOIN [dbo].[Employees] ON [dbo].[Employees].EmployeeID = [dbo].[Orders].EmployeeID
GROUP BY [dbo].[Orders].EmployeeID,[Orders].FirstName,[Orders].Lastname;
```